# Moving button on top of image

Tags: html, css, button

I have two buttons that need to be moved on top of image. One button should be on right side of an image, and another one on the left side. However at the moment they stick at the bottom left corner of the image, while they should be on separate sides in the middle of photo. What I am doing wrong?

HTML part:

```
<div class="container">
              <img class="mySlides" src="images/dog1.jpg" style="width:100%">
              <img class="mySlides" src="images/dog2.jpg" style="width:100%">
              <img class="mySlides" src="images/dog3.jpg" style="width:100%">
              <img class="mySlides" src="images/dog4.jpg" style="width:100%">

              <button class="carousell-button carousell-button-black carousell-button-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
              <button class="carousell-button carousell-button-black carousell-button-right" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</button>
        </div>
```

CSS part:

```
.container carousell-button-right {
    position: relative;
    top: 200%px;
    right: 0%;
}
.container carousell-button-left {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0%;
}
```

How it looks right now:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nk3j1.png)

Comment: You are missing the `.` in your selectors. `.container .carousell-button-right { }`

Comment: `200%px` isn't valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. since you need it in the middle then use `Relative` to parent and use `absolute` for `Right` as well. This will make sure it is positioned absolutely middle based on the image size.
> 2. You should also use `.` for the `carousell` class.
> 3. As mentioned in the comments above `200%px;` is an invalid property value.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}

.container .carousell-button-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.container .carousell-button-left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="mySlides" src="http://placekitten.com/301/301" style="width:100%">
  <button class="carousell-button carousell-button-black carousell-button-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
  <button class="carousell-button carousell-button-black carousell-button-right" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Look at the snippet below and try to use flex-box

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: black;
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

button {
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button>btn</button>
  <button>btn</button>
</div>
```